# Are there actual technical realizations of the Carnot cycle?

Tags: thermodynamics, heat-engine, carnot-cycle

The Carnot cycle is composed of four steps: isothermal expansion, adiabatic expansion, isothermal compression and adiabatic compression.

In the case of combustion engines, we have the idealized Otto cycle and the actual Otto engine. At least for pedagogical purposes, it would be very nice to see an actual Carnot engine which tries to approximately implement the Carnot cycle.

So are there such technical realizations?

(Note that I'm not asking for a truly reversible engine nor whether a Carnot engine would be useful in practise.)

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_engine

Comment: The Stirling cycle doesn't involve adiabatic steps but isochoric ones.

Comment: Turbine systems can (and do) closely approximate adiabatic expansion and compression, but I'm not aware right off of systems that also do good approximations to isothermal expansion and compression.

Comment: the Rankine cycle without superheating is a pretty good approximation to the Carnot cycle. ( https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rankine_cycle )